# Undefined symbol dlsyn when installing posgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, libpq

I am trying to install postresql on a docker container based on buster.
It used to work, now devops changed the base image and s*** hit the fan.

So I am running `apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib` and on setup I get the following error:

```
o   /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/initdb: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined symbol: dlsym 
Error: initdb failed 
Error: could not create default cluster.
```

ldd on libpq looks reasonable and similar to the one I got on the old image.

Where would you suggest to start looking? Anything useful I could compare between the two?
The new image is meant to be multi arch to support ARM, so maybe something went wrong with the linkage there?

Thank you!

Comment: Which Linux distribution is that?

Comment: It's Debian buster. But it doesn't matter as they tweak little things there, like this libpq. It took me some time to find it out.

Comment: Can it be a 32/64 bit collision? What does `readelf -d /usr/local/lib/libpq.so.5 | grep libdl.so` say? (Or `file /usr/local/lib/libpq.so.5` on the first place.)

Comment: Both the good and the bad versions are 64bit. In ldd or readelf both of them do not show ldl, no idea why. There's a difference though, the bad one is linked with librt.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously someone uses a private version of libpq. 
Found the offending version, I'll make them fix it or bring the old one back.